# How do we add the Job Submit Plugin API in Slurm running on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, lua, slurm, workload

I have been using this [link](https://github.com/nateGeorge/slurm_gpu_ubuntu) to install the Slurm Workload Manager to Ubuntu 20.04.

I would like to enable the Job Submit Plugin API to execute the `job_submit.lua`. After adding the line `JobSubmitPlugins=lua` into `slurm.conf` I get the error:

[2022-04-28T16:06:44.910] error: Couldn't find the specified plugin name for job_submit/lua looking at all files 
[2022-04-28T16:06:44.912] error: cannot find job_submit plugin for job_submit/lua 
[2022-04-28T16:06:44.912] error: cannot create job_submit context for job_submit/lua 
[2022-04-28T16:06:44.912] fatal: failed to initialize job_submit plugin

Many people fixed this in RedHat by installing the Lua library. I did the same for Ubuntu, but it did not work. How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you invoke `job_submit.lua`?  Where did you specify the `job_submit.lua` filename?

Comment: I have specified the `job_submit.lua` inside `etc/slurm`. I got the `job_submit.lua` from an old server that can limit the number of GPUs being used for a job depending on the partition type.

Comment: The error looks like the code is invoking wrong `require'job_submit.lua'` instead of correct `require'job_submit'`  Try to remove file extension.

Comment: I removed the file extension and that did not work.

Comment: Please show the line where you specified `job_submit.lua`

Comment: On ```slurm.conf```, I don't think you specify ```job_submit.lua``` in it. Instead, you need to write ```JobSubmitPlugins=lua```. Anyways, I was able to solve the problem by installing liblua5.2-dev and recompiling slurm. But it is still not executing the ```job_submit.lua```.